# How to access tr id with jQuery in table mouseover even?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I tried the below to get the `<TR>` id from the table row which has a mouse over event, however I get undefined. Please suggest a way to get the id in the below function.

The below needs fix, my console out of **keyfromTable** throws `undefined`.

> eval(JSON.stringify($('tr').attr('id')));

```
$('table').on('mouseenter', 'tr', function() {
    var tr=$(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!insidePopover) {
             var keyfromTable = eval(JSON.stringify($('tr').attr('id')));
             console.log(keyfromTable);
                   $.getJSON( "http://localhost:8111/app/rest/builds/id:137/artifacts/content/additionalInfo.json", function(data) {
                    result = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    var items = [];
                        for (var key in obj) { 
                            var keyfromJson = eval(key);

                    //console.log(" OUTSIDE IF " + keyfromJson + " " + keyfromTable + " ");
                            if (keyfromJson == keyfromTable) {
                            //items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + obj[key]['Fi'] + "</li>" );
                            console.log("Inside IF " + keyfromJson + " " + keyfromTable + " ");

                            }
                        }
                    $('tr').attr('data-content', keyfromTable);
                    $(tr).popover('show');
                    attachEvents(tr);

            });
}
}, 20);
 });
```

Comment: replace `$('tr')` with `tr` <<< `tr` here comes from `var tr=$(this);`

Comment: tr is in quotes when defining keyfromTable?

Comment: when you don't see the messed up logic or the extra quotation marks in this case!

Comment: Thanks can you guys mark your answer please.